# how to fix TypeError: state.user.currentUser is null node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, local-storage

in requestmethods.js

```
    import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user)
  ?.currentUser?.accessToken;

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});
export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

and in app.js

```
function App() {
  const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        {admin && (
          <>
            <Topbar />
            <div className="container">
              <Sidebar />
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/users">
                <UserList />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/user/:userId">
                <User />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/newUser">
                <NewUser />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/products">
                <ProductList />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/product/:productId">
                <Product />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/newproduct">
                <NewProduct />
              </Route>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I am trying to make if the user is admin show the admin pages, if not show the login page , but when I run npm start I get blank screen , when inspect the page I get these types of error

1=> Uncaught TypeError: state.user.currentUser is null

```
 const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin);
```

[image]

Comment: You should check currentUser exists before accessing its property.  const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser?.isAdmin);

Comment: ok the error gone but nothing to display

Comment: if i deleted the token in requestmethods.js , admin in apps.js it will display the admin project

Comment: then there is something wrong with your state management. Make sure you fetch the currentUser and assign. Your code doesn't show whether you do it. "?" is useful for initial render when the currentUser isn't fetched yet.

Answer (score 0):

*Uncaught TypeError: state.user.currentUser is null*

This states that the **currentUser** property in your **state.user** object is null hence it cannot read the **isAdmin** property.

One way to avoid this use the safe(elvis) operator '?'.

So use **state?.user?.currentUser?.isAdmin** instead of **state.user.currentUser.isAdmin**

Comment: the error gone but nothing to display

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using react-router v6, your app.js could look like this

```
function App() {
  const admin = useSelector((state) => state?.user?.currentUser?.isAdmin);
  const RequireAuth = () => {
    if (!admin) {
      return Navigate('/login');
    }

    return <Outlet/>;
  };


  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
            <Topbar />
            <div className="container">
              <Sidebar />
              <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/users">
                <UserList />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/user/:userId">
                <User />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/newUser">
                <NewUser />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/products">
                <ProductList />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/product/:productId">
                <Product />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/newproduct">
                <NewProduct />
              </Route>
              </Route>
            </div>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

You have a good article [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-authentication-with-react-router-v6/)